# android custom keyboard paint some keys

Tags: java, android

I am starting some tutorials in Android and I'm trying to make a custom keyboard.
It looks great but I would like to paint some keys. So I extend my class to `KeyboardView` and implement `onDraw()` function. When I debug my keyboard it never goes to my onDraw function. Here are some parts of my code.

```
public class CustomKeyboard extends KeyboardView {

    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;

    public CustomKeyboard(Activity host,  AttributeSet attrs, int viewid, int layoutid) {
        super(host, attrs);

        mHostActivity= host;
        mKeyboardView= (KeyboardView)mHostActivity.findViewById(viewid);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(mHostActivity, layoutid));
        mKeyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(false);
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(mOnKeyboardActionListener);
        mHostActivity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        List&lt;Key&gt; keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {
            if(key.label != null)
            canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How were you able to debug your keyboard?

Comment: I have layout with some editTexts and my keyboard